# Swift pop all view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with following structure

```
--TabBarController
  --HomeController
  --CameraNavigationController
    --CameraController
    --UploadController
  --ProfileController
```

in the viewDidload method of CameraController shows [fusuma](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma) view and thereafter upon selecting an image shows UploadController.

My issue is when in uploadController if I click Home in tabbar it goes to Home but If I click Camera in tab bar after this it directly goes to UploadController and not CameraController and does not load Fusuma.

I want to load cameraController everytime I click on the button in tab bar how to do that?

This is my code to load UploadViewController

```
 func fusumaImageSelected(_ image: UIImage, source: FusumaMode) {

    let vc = ImageUploadViewController()
    vc.selectedImage = image

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: The application is working fine.  You have a tab Bar Controller & when you click Camera in Tab bar initially it will show Camera Controller and then Upload Controller, so on top of navigation we have Upload Controller. So when you come back to camera from another tab, it will still show Upload Controller as it is on top. 
Try popping from Upload Controller to Camera Controller, switch tabs and then you will get to know how it works.

Comment: @bhatejaud i want to load cameracontroller everytime the button is clicked in tabbar how to achieve that?

Comment: In viewDidDissapear() methos of update controller, add the following:
1. if your are using navaigation controller then add:
self.navigationController.popViewController()

2. If you are presenting uploadController then add this:
self.dismiss()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following code to `CameraNavigationController` (assuming it's your custom class for `UINavigationController`. If it's not, please create a new one and add following code in it),

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the behavior of tabbar is exactly what you see in your project.
You want to do something additionally and the way I could suggest is monitoring tabbar selection and do what you want to do.

this method in delegate class observe tabbar actions:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                     didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

at this method you could check if your camera tab is presenting upload controller pop the navigation to root view, this causes when you switch back to camera tab, you see CameraController

May you find better way to handle this, it is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set tabbar index as root ViewController then presnt the cameraVC after this.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let popToVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[((self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count)!)-5] else { return }
        navigationController?.popToViewController(popToVC, animated: true)
```

**This solution is for If you want to navigate back to your specific view controller. I have used -5 to navigate back to the 5th screen. You can use your number as per your root view hierarchy**